# Import or Add code to an add-in dynamically

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am working on a project where I have created a PowerPoint addin. The concept is this will only contain an user form, with a list box. Based on the user selection other modules (bas files) will be added or imported to the presentation and the code will be executed.

I don't want to include all the modules in the add in as depending upon the requirement I can do the modification and then can store in a shared folder. So every time user uses the addin they can have the updated version. So I don't have to re circulate the addin with every change.

I have a blank module where i import the code from a text file (code from bas file saved as text) and it runs.

I can import the bas files, also using inserFrom file option I can import code from a text file, but problem is it's always getting added to the current presentation code window. But I want to add the code to the addin code pane.

I have a blank module in the addin called "tempCode", where I want to update the imported code, but I am not able to do so.

It works fine when I am editing the addin as a ppt, but when I convert ppt to an addin the concept is not working.

Any ideas how I can add the code to the addin code pane rather adding to the active ppt.

Code details:

I have a user form, with a list box.
It has 3 items.
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
If user selects any option, let's say option 2, the code for option 2 will be imported from a text file to the working module.

And a command button to run the selected.

Name of working module is “Mod_Working”
Name of text file is “C:\Code\Option2.txt”

Below is the code I am using:

```
Sub ImportSelected()
With ActivePresentation.VBProject.VBComponents(“Mod_Working”).CodeModule
    .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines 'it deletes any existing code
    .AddFromFile “C:\Code\Option2.txt”
End With
End Sub

Code in text file:
Sub Test
 Msgbox “You selected Opt 2”
End sub

Code of Command Button:
Private Sub Cmd_run_Click()
   Application.Run “Mod_Working.Test”
End Sub
```

This works in ppt mode but not when converted to addin.

Comment: If you show your existing code it will be easier to suggest changes.  However, it might be easier to make your add-in just a "stub" which then loads the "real" add-in from the shared folder.  That way it will always be up-to-date, and you can also manage changes to ribbon items which you may create.  (Make sure to tag the shared add-in in the folder as "read-only")

Comment: Have you set the registry key to show PowerPoint addins in Project Explorer?

Comment: The code I am using:

Sub ImportSelected()
With ActivePresentation.VBProject.VBComponents(“Mod_Working”).CodeModule
    .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines 'it deletes any existing code
    .AddFromFile “C:\Code\Option2.txt”
End With
End Sub

Code in text file:
Sub Test
 Msgbox “You selected Opt 2”
End sub

Code of Command Button:
Private Sub Cmd_run_Click()
   Application.Run “Mod_Working.Test”
End Sub

This works in ppt mode but not when converted to addin.

Tim, can you please explain the stub concept bit more.

Also, I don't have access to registry as it's my office system

Comment: Sorry for the messy post, can't do better in this comment box, please let me know if I can post it better, I am very new to this forum

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this:
- In the shared folder, mark the add-in file as read-only (right-click, properties). This prevents the file being in-use when people are using the add-in (at least it works that way in Excel)
- When you have an update, simply replace the add-in and set it to read-only again.

Alternatively, check out: [www.jkp-ads.com/articles/updateanaddin.asp](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/updateanaddin.asp)

Comment: Thank you... But I want to keep the program dynamic, I will just dump the code in a folder and depending on the contents of it the form should display the list and execute. The form I want to use just as a lunching pad and the addin should online able to call the code rather than containing the code. The files it will handle are very dynamic and format changes a lot. So I want the concept, if any error is there I will debug n store in the folder, user just have to reload the form. Is it possible anyway?

Comment: It is possible to import modules indeed, but you will have to change an Excel security setting for all involved users (Allow access to VBAproject).

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, but here I m trying to import the modules or code within the addin.